# Finding simulated values of $X$ given that $U(0,1)$ is $.618$.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

You decide to simulate a random variable. You generate a value on $U(0,1)$ of $.618$. What is your simulated value of $X$ if:

a) $X$ is $U(0,10)$?

b) $X$ follows $F(x) = 1 - e^{-2x}$?

c) $X$ is $N(0,1)$?

Attempted Solutions:

a) I am assuming $U(0,1)$ means every possible outcome in the event space is equally likely to occur. I am not sure then what the simulated value would be for $X$ but I would guess $6.18$?

b) I am not sure where to start. I recall seeing that  $f(x) = F'(x)$ so $f(x) = 2e^{-2x}$

c) Apparently, $N(0,1)$ means $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and wiki says the curve in this special case where $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma^2 = 1$ maxes out at $1\over{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ so I suppose that would be the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to find the value $X$ for each distribution that has $0.618$ of the area to the left of it.  This would be represented as $CDF(X)=0.618$ or $\int_{-\infty}^X pdf(x)dx = 0.618$  In a, you are correct it is $6.18$.  For b, you are given the CDF, so solve the equation.  For c, you need to use the z-score table for the normal distribution.

Comment: For (b) do I set pdf = $2e^{2x}$ and look for the upper limit that makes it equal to .618?

Comment: That would work, but you have the CDF so can use it.  You just want $0.618=1-e^{-2X}$.

Comment: For (c) I got .3 because the z score associated with .618 is .3 and a standard deviation is just 1. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right for c

Comment: Cool, and for (b) I obtained .4812

Comment: Appreciate the help by the way, thank you